# Direction of momentum and group velocity of electron in a solid

Tags: waves, dispersion

So I am looking at the dispersion relation of electrons in a solid i.e. a $E(k_y)$ plot and I am being bugged by a very basic question about wave propagation. If $v_g = \partial E/\partial(k_y) > 0$ then the group velocity is along positive $y$ direction, while $k_y$ can in principle be negative. Now, I know that the crystal momentum $k\hbar$  is not the same as the momentum of a free particle, but still I do not find an intuitive explanation of how to understand a particle with positive group velocity and negative (crystal) momentum. Anyone has something wise to say about my little conundrum? How to look at it and where does the analogy to a free particle i.e. $v=\frac{p}{m}$ break?

Thanks,
Krystian